# implode array value as individual string using php

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have an array values as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sept
    [1] => Oct
    [2] => Dec
)
```

Want to combine it like this:

```
'Sep','Oct','Dec'
```

I tried using **implode** function: `implode(",",$data);`

but it is giving me output as `Sept,Oct,Dec`

Is there any other way to print this?

Comment: $array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone

Comment: function add_quotes($str) {
    return sprintf("'%s'", $str);
}

$final =  implode(',', array_map('add_quotes', $array));